# UIAlertView ClickedButtonAtIndex Will Not Save Integer

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have made a `UIAlertView` of which the 2nd button is supposed to reset the score back to 0.

Here is my UIAlertView code:

```
- (IBAction)showActionSheetReset:(id)sender
{
    UIAlertView *resetAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Delete And Reset Score"
                                                         message:@"Are You sure You Want To Reset The Score Shown on the Engligh Page? This WILL NOT affect your High Score on Game Center."
                                                        delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"No, Don't Erase"
                                               otherButtonTitles:@"Yes, Reset Score", nil];

    [resetAlertView show];
    resetAlertView.tag = 2;
}

- (void)alertViewReset:(UIAlertView *)alertViewReset clickedButtonAtIndex:       (NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (alertViewReset.tag == 2) {
        if (buttonIndex == 1) {
            [self resetTheScore];

        }
    }
}
```

And here is my `resetTheScore` method:

```
- (IBAction)resetTheScore
{
    self.currentScore = 0;
    currentScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld", self.currentScore];
    [self counterDefaults:self];
}
```

And Here is my `counterDefaults` method:

```
- (IBAction)counterDefaults:(id)sender
{
    NSUserDefaults *Defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [Defaults setInteger:self.currentScore forKey:TapCount];
    [Defaults synchronize];
}
```

Why doesn't it save?

Comment: I'm wondering how did this compile with the missing closing quotes...

Answer (score 0):

The `UIAlertViewDelegate` method is called `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` not `alertViewReset:clickedButtonAtIndex:`.

Your function `alertViewReset:clickedButtonAtIndex:` never gets called. Correct the name and it should be fine.

Comment: Remember: breakpoints are your friend. 
If you expect your code to do something, enter breakpoints and see if it actually hits your code.
Secondly, if your breakpoints are hit, use the Debug Area to check variables for their expected values. (Or you could place `NSLog()` statements to output variables in the log).